# How to tell what shell is running from command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh, environment-variables

If I do `sudo zsh`, I can tell I am in zsh by examining `ps -ef`

Is there an **easier** way?  `echo $SHELL` says it's `/bin/sh`, because $SHELL is always the default shell, not necessarily the shell that's actually running.

Comment: What about `[[ ! -z "$SUDO_COMMAND" ]] && echo $SUDO_COMMAND || echo $SHELL` ?

Comment: That works, thanks.  However, `[[ ! -z "$SUDO_COMMAND" ]] && echo $SUDO_COMMAND` also works.  If the first part (`[[ … ]]` fails, will it exit and do nothing?  Or will it do the third part which will say /bin/sh (which is wrong).  Although it works, it's not an easier way.  Also, if I'm running a script that doesn't have a bang line (perl?) or a compiled executable, then $SUDO_COMMAND will be the name of the script or executable.  I suppose then, it's not in any shell, but if it calls something else, it might want to check the shell.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you want sudo to always use zsh, do `sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh root`

Comment: I guess a slightly easier way is `env | grep COM` or just `env` and look for SUDO_COMMAND.

Comment: A number of other options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on.  I've had some luck with `ps -fp $$`, but there are times when that won't work.

Comment: Wow, rather complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I happen to be on some *interactive shell*, and just want to quickly verify what kind of shell it is, I usually do a

```
)
```

If I'm in zsh, I get

```
zsh: parse error near `)'
```

, bash says

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

and dash and ash also reveal their name in this way. I guess that this approach would also work with csh, tcsh and ksh.

Comment: Also works for fish - and sort of for xonsh

Comment: Even simpler than the previous answer.  Plus this one will also work in a script.  In a script, $0 gives the name of the script and not the shell.  On the other hand, in a script, this one would require parsing stderr to get the shell name.

Comment: @WGroleau: Querying the parameter `$0` is not related to stderr. However `$0` contains whatever the calling process passes as _name_ to the invoked program. For instance, login shells are sometimes invoked under a different name (`-zsh` instead of `zsh` is frequently used), and if you invoke a shell via a symlink, `$0` contains that symlink path. Aside from this, I don't quite see why you want to query this in a script. If you write a script, you **know** what language you are using. It's like, if you write a Fortran program, you don't want to query whether your program is Fortran or Ada.

Comment: The method depends on the error message.  Doesn't that message get sent to stderr?  The bang line of a script might determine the shell, or it could specify perl.  Moreover, the parameters passed to the script are parsed by the shell.  However, the question was specifically concerning an interactive shell, and therefore, I accepted this answer.

Comment: Anyway, your answer did not say anything about $0.  The other one did.  That's why I pointed out that your answer, by NOT using $0, might also work in a script, even though that was not the question I asked.

Answer (score 5):

To get the current shell, you can run:

```
echo $0
```

To get the the default shell, you can run:

```
echo $SHELL
```

Comment: Coments showed another way, but this is definitely the simplest so far.

Comment: "Gairfowl" points to a lot of options, but for my question (taken literally), this is the simplest.

Comment: This only works for POSIX and csh type shells